# consultar un elemento en una tabla (python)

Tags: python

estoy intentando importar una tabla de excel y poder extraer un valor de la misma pero no estoy pudiendo, llevo algo asi

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Nadia Mendez\Desktop\programas de nadia\htdocs\Python\tabla\libro.csv')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['nombre','apellido','dni','direccion'])
print (df)

valor=""
def vervalor():
    valor=int(input("Ingrese un valor: (0=nombre, 1=apellido,2=dni,3=direccion)"))
    return ("El valor ingresado es;"+valor)
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema que presentas, tienes algún error? o que pasó?

Comment: pude importar la tabla pero la función no se me ejecuta

Comment: por que nunca la llamas `vervalor()`

Comment: lo hice pero no me devuelve nada

Comment: tienes que hacer `resultado = vervalor()` y luego haces `print(resultado)`

Answer (score 0):

Como consejo trata de ser mas especifica en los errores que tienes. tu código tiene algunos problemas de lógica, pues que pasa si el usuario ingresa una opción invalida?

Para evitar ese problema y no crear varios bloques de `if/else` creamos un diccionario donde la clave será un numero y el valor será la opción

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Nadia Mendez\Desktop\programas de nadia\htdocs\Python\tabla\libro.csv')   

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['nombre','apellido','dni','direccion'])

#creamos el diccionario
opciones = {0:"nombre", 1:"apellido", 2:"dni", 3:"direccion"}

def vervalor():
    valor=int(input("Ingrese un valor: (0=nombre, 1=apellido,2=dni,3=direccion)"))
    #comprobamos que exista la opccion
    if valor in opciones.keys():
        res = df[opciones[valor]] #retornamos la columna
        return res

#ejecutamos la funcion
valor = vervalor()
print(valor)
```

Lo que hará la función será retornar todos los datos de la columna que haya sido seleccionada mediante el input, esto es una forma dinámica de hacerlo y además mucho mas simple y reducida.